# Error in my code but i cant find out how to fix

Tags: php, mysql, mysqli

Not able to connect to the database.
My error:

> [Sat Jul 29 23:02:56.747139 2017] [proxy_fcgi:error] [pid 13049:tid 140689614522112] [] AH01071: Got error 'PHP message: PHP Warning:  mysqli::mysqli(): (HY000/1045): Access denied for user 'timavnl_1'@'localhost' (using password: YES) in /home/timavnl/domains/tim-av.nl/public_html/6628/job/db_connect.php on line 2\nPHP message: PHP Warning:  mysqli::prepare(): Couldn't fetch mysqli in /home/timavnl/domains/tim-av.nl/public_html/6628/job/index.php on line 5\nPHP message: PHP Warning:  main(): Couldn't fetch mysqli in /home/timavnl/domains/tim-av.nl/public_html/6628/job/index.php on line 10\nPHP message: PHP Notice:  Trying to get property of non-object in /home/timavnl/domains/tim-av.nl/public_html/6628/job/index.php on line 23\nPHP message: PHP Fatal error:  Call to a member function fetch() on null in /home/timavnl/domains/tim-av.nl/public_html/6628/job/index.php on line 24\n'

My DB connect code:

```
<?php
$db = new mysqli("localhost","timavnl_1","password"."timavnl_1") or 
die("ERROR! With connection");
?>
```

index.php code:
[Picture of: index.php](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vOHVR.jpg)

Comment: The code is fine, you have problem with database credentials.

Comment: just with your error, the problem is about your attempt to create a connection to you database 

`PHP Warning: mysqli::mysqli(): (HY000/1045): Access denied for user 'timavnl_1'@'localhost' (using password: YES) in /home/timavnl/domains/tim-av.nl/public_html/6628/job/db_connect.php on line 2`

Why you have this error ? Don't know without code but it have to do with your credentials

Comment: This is a duplicate of at least a dozen previous questions here. Please have the courtesy to at least do a basic search (via Google or this site) on the *exact error message* you're getting to see if there is a solution already available before posting a new question.

Comment: check my answer

Comment: I removed -- RESOLVED  from the title. If an answer solved it, consider accepting the answer or post one yourself or delete the question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have a typo mistake. You have given `.` after password, change this with `,`, use like this

```
"<"?php $db = new mysqli("localhost","timavnl_1","password","timavnl_1") or die("ERROR! With connection"); ?>
```

The right syntax for make a `connection` object is, parameters must be sephrated by `,` operator.

**Syntax**

```
$mysqli = new mysqli("localhost", "user", "password", "database");
```

**Note:** Depending on the `connection` function used, assorted parameters can be `omitted`. If a parameter is not provided, then the extension attempts to use the default values that are set in the PHP configuration file. Check the mannual [here](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.quickstart.connections.php)

Answer (score 0):

The DB connect code appears to have a period `.` instead of a `,` between the password and database name.

ref: http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.quickstart.connections.php

Try the following instead:

```
"<"?php $db = new mysqli("localhost","timavnl_1","password","timavnl_1") or die("ERROR! With connection"); ?>
```